# Android Building JSON Object

Tags: android, json

Im trying to add a value to a JSONObject that is passed into this function. The problem is that when i try to add it with a key, it does not get included. When i print out the string representation of it, the identifier key is not included.

The rest of the function works correctly. The if statements gets executed and identifier has a value. Its not null. I appreciate any ideas.

```
    public String issueWebRequest(String path, JSONObject array, boolean boolIdentifier){

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        if(boolIdentifier){
            array.put("identifier", identifier);
        }
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(array.toString());
```

Comment: where does identifier come from? Are you sure it's not null?

Comment: the value is not set right after the `if` statement, of when you pass it to the `StringEntity`?

Comment: yes im sure its not null. Yeah if i print out array.toString(). it does not have the identifier key.